# What Apple computers are shown in this MacBook Pro Reveal video?

Tags: apple, identify-this-computer

In this [Reveal video for the new MacBook Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDpOB-OXypQ), seven or eight vintage Apple products are shown. Which ones exactly are they?

The other question similar to this one is asking about a completely different Apple commercial.

### Screenshots

Order is left to right, top to bottom.  Click to embiggen.

[image: Laptop 1]
[image: Laptop 2]
[image: Laptop 3]
[image: Laptop 4]
[image: Laptop 5]
[image: Laptop 6]
[image: Laptop 7]
[image: Laptop 8]
[image: Laptop 9]
[image: Laptop 10]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What typewriters and computers are shown in this commercial?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/what-typewriters-and-computers-are-shown-in-this-commercial)

Comment: @pndc These questions are about two different commercials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order:

- one of the first PowerBooks, either a [140](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_140) or a [170](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_170);
- one of the colour [PowerBook 500 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_500_series);
- a [Wallstreet Series II PowerBook G3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_G3#PowerBook_G3_Series_.28Wallstreet_Series_II.2C_AKA_PDQ.29) (spot the CD-ROM drive, and rounded touchpad);
- an [iBook G3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBook#iBook_G3_.28.22Clamshell.22.29);
- an [Titanium PowerBook G4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_G4#Titanium_PowerBook_G4);
- an [white polycarbonate MacBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook#Original_polycarbonate_model);
- a [MacBook Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air) (you can read the model below the screen);
- a [third-generation (Retina) MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Third_generation_.28Retina.29);
- a [MacBook Retina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_(Retina));
- the new touch-bar [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Fourth_generation_.28Touch_Bar.29).

Comment: I actually think that's a Titanium PowerBook, not an Aluminium, and after that it's a plastic MacBook (branding visible, otherwise near-indistinguishable from the iBook before it), agreed on a MacBook Air on the envelope, but then an outgoing Pro, a MacBook Retina, and then the new Pro.

Comment: I thought it looked like my old G4 Ti-book as well (the predecessor of the Al, if I remember right).

Comment: Thanks @Tommy — at least I got the retro models right ;-). I’d forgotten the Pro had a Retina screen, that’s what confused me (the zebra picture was used for the Retina launch IIRC, at least I associated it with Retina).